# CORS enabled endpoint in AWS API Gateway with Terraform`

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I'm attempting to build a simple AWS API Gateway with terraform. This API will connect over AWS Lambda as a proxy integration. I have no issues either with API integration or working of it. My attempt to connect from a client application (React/Angular) throws CORS issues. Here's the code I used to create CORS enabled endpoint. And this endpoint is connected to Lambda - 'gg_events_dynlambda_api'.
This code continuously fails on 'response_parameters' in 'gg_events_options_response_200' with the error

```
 An argument named "response_parameters" is not expected here.
```

As a person trying to get into Terraform, this is a huge limitation to overcome. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_method" "gg_events_options_method" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gg_rest_api_gateway.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.gg_events_dynlambda_api.id}"
  http_method   = "OPTIONS"
  authorization = "NONE"
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_method_response" "gg_events_options_response_200" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gg_rest_api_gateway.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.gg_events_dynlambda_api.id}"
  http_method   = "${aws_api_gateway_method.gg_events_options_method.http_method}"
  status_code = "200"

  response_models = {
    "application/json" = "Empty"
  }

  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = true
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = true
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = true
  }
  depends_on = [aws_api_gateway_method.gg_events_options_method]
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "options_integration" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gg_rest_api_gateway.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.gg_events_dynlambda_api.id}"
  http_method   = "${aws_api_gateway_method.gg_events_options_method.http_method}"
  type          = "MOCK"
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_method.options_method"]
}
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration_response" "options_integration_response" {
  rest_api_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.gg_rest_api_gateway.id}"
  resource_id   = "${aws_api_gateway_resource.gg_events_dynlambda_api.id}"
  http_method   = "${aws_api_gateway_method.gg_events_options_method.http_method}"
  status_code   = "${aws_api_gateway_method_response.gg_events_options_response_200.status_code}"
  response_parameters = {
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "'Content-Type,X-Amz-Date,Authorization,X-Api-Key,X-Amz-Security-Token'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "'GET,OPTIONS,POST,PUT'",
    "method.response.header.Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "'*'"
  }
  depends_on = ["aws_api_gateway_method_response.options_200"]
}
```

Comment: The code looks ok so far. Have you tried to update the AWS provider and Terraform? Furthermore, check your `depends_on` statements. Some use "strings" instead of resource references. That does not work.

Comment: What version of Terraform and the AWS provider are you running? [`response_parameters` was added in v2.0.0](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/blob/release/2.x/CHANGELOG.md#200-february-27-2019) over 2 years ago but if you're running a particularly old version of the provider then that would explain it.

Comment: Let me try updating Terraform